# Debian bookworm: Long delay when starting application via ssh -X

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, x11-forwarding, debian-bookworm

I have a new vanilla Debian bookworm installation on a laptop. Everything works as intended but when I connect to it with `ssh -X` and start any application (e.g. `gedit`) there is a delay of ~ 25 seconds before the window opens. Once opened, there is no delay/lag.

- There is no output in the terminal.
- Commands without UI are not affected (e.g. `nano`).
- Closing and opening the same command/application has the same lag.
- It does not matter whether I connect as root or as an unprivileged user.
- Network issues can be ruled out (Gigabit LAN).